# Android - Display a single Activity using two xml files

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-xml

I had developed `Android` app having some screens with common UI format.

The format in top-down approach is:

1. Title Header (Two `buttons`, `ImageView`)
2. Content Area- It will differ among Activities (contains ListView, Tabs, Buttons, TextView, WebView....)
3. Footer Layout (`Relative Layout` with three `Imagebuttons`)

I want to reformat the code in such a way that one `xml` contains Title Header and Footer Layout and other `xml` contains `ListView`,Tabs, Buttons.. based on the usage. Can i acheive this? Please help me with sample code/links....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the include element to have sub-xml files:

```
<LinearLayout ... >
    <include layout="@layout/header" />
    <include layout="@layout/content" />
    <include layout="@layout/footer" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This will allow you to easily create layouts that reuse these pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Use  tag.

```
      <include 
        android:id="@+id/some_id_if_needed"
        layout="@layout/some_layout"/>
```

Also, read [Merging Layouts articles](http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/25/android-layout-trick-2-include-to-reuse/).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `include` tag. You can reuse your layouts. All you need to do is include them:

```
<include
android:id="@+id/layout_id"
layout="@layout/layout_name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add more xml in the actvity view using include tag just see this http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html.

For example, In your case,

1. In your main.xml, use Relative layout
2. Add separate xml for header, add using  tag add in main.xml
3. Add relative layout in main.xml, use height as wrap content and add listview
4. Add separate relative layout xml for footer, add using  tag add in main.xml and use  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take advantage of the Inheritance in java. Have a `BaseActivity` where you define all common things among your activities and extend this and set content in all child activities. In the `BaseActivity`'s layout have an empty layout for content, later in child activities you can fill the content using [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html).

Pseudo code:

```
BaseActivity extends Activity{
    View mBody;
    void onCreate(Bundle prevState){
        super.onCreate(prevState);
        setContentView(R.layout.baselayout);
        mBody = findViewById(R.id.body)
    }

    void setBody(int bodyLaout){
        //here populate the mView using LayoutInflater
    }
}

Activity1 extends BaseActivity{
    void onCreate(...){
        super.onCreate(...);
        setBody(R.layout.activity_one);
    }
}
```